# Mapping column names from a query

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am trying to add custom search suggestions to my android app by querying a SQLLite database I have setup using the Room Persistence Library.

Android requires me to set certain column names in the cursor I return which are different from the column names I have currently set in the database. Is there an easy way to map the column names in my database to the column names android requires for custom search suggestions?

Comment: What is the name which android requires to you?

Comment: do you want your suggestions to be used by your app only? or you want them to be visible in system wide search?

Comment: My my app only. I am trying to change the column name to be SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1

Comment: Right now I am just using .query and concating the SQL statement but was wondering if there is a better way of doing this with Room.

Comment: so you don need that `SearchManager` stuff at all - just use `Searchview.OnQueryTextListener`

Comment: I am implementing it using the method provided here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions. Is is better just to do Searchview.OnQueryTextListener and inflate my own suggestion dialog?

Comment: ok first try `Searchview#setSuggestionsAdapter()` method, pass `SimpleCursorAdapter`and setup its `FilterQueryProvider` - if it is what you need you dont have to do anything else

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot. Was starting to do it that way and then read the documentation and decided to approach it the way it is written there. Your way definitely sounds much easier. Don't know why Google suggests to do it the way they do.

Comment: because their way is when the suggestions are used by global, system-wide suggestions subsystem - it has to be more complex by definition

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the help